Experiencing Multiple Flat Tires on Kross Evado 1.0 – Seeking Advice and Product Recommendations
I have a Kross Evado 1.0 hybrid bike. Over the past two months, I've faced persistent issues with flat tires. Initially, I discovered a small hole in the rear inner tube, so I purchased a new Schwalbe AV17 (28/47-622) inner tube. However, after just two weeks of use, the rear tire went flat again.
Upon inspection, I found a super tiny dot-sized hole in the new inner tube, which was not in the same location as the previous hole. I also checked the outer tire and noticed some small debris, possibly remnants of glass, but there wasn’t much noticeable damage.
I want to avoid purchasing another inner tube that will develop a hole after a short time. Here are the options I’m considering:

Buy a new inner tube with extra puncture protection:

Continental Tour 28 All with extra puncture belt (€15-€20) or Schwalbe Marathon series (€20-€25).


Consider self-healing inner tubes:

Slime Self-Sealing Inner Tube (€15-€20) or Continental Tour 28 Self-Healing Tube (€20-€25).
Note: I will also need a new outer tire for compatibility with self-healing options.


Replace the outer tire with one that has better puncture resistance:

Bontrager AW3 Hard-Case (€40-€50) or Continental Contact Plus (€35-€45) for excellent puncture protection.


Take the bike to a professional mechanic to identify any underlying issues that may be causing the repeated flats (~€20-€50 depending on the service).

Any advice on which option would be the best course of action or any additional product recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Slime Self-Sealing Inner Tube In my experience, thinner tires tend to use too high a pressure for sealant to work well, if at all.  28s would likely in this range.  But it's not completely clear what size you're using.  And did you remount the tire in the same place when you replaced the tube?  If not, the hole in the tube may still have lined up with the same spot on the tire - which would be where the problem is.  That's one reason why a lot of people always mount a tire the same way, usually with the largest sidewall label centered on the valve stem.

Note that product recommendations are off-topic here, but as general advice, better to stick brands that are specialized in tires (Schwalbe, Continental, Michelin, ...). Brands like Bontrager are "captive brands" (of Trek in this case), they source their tires from external suppliers and apply a markup to make some profit.

According to the Evado web site your bike came with Mitas Gravel / V84 Gripper - 42-622 tyres and these are pretty cheap. It's possible the tyres just don't offer enough resistance to the sharp debris we inevitably encounter while riding.
I'm saying this because I recently had a very similar experience. I bought a new Pinnacle Lithium 2, which I think is in roughly the same price bracket as your bicycle, and I got two punctures in the first two weeks of riding it. I replaced the tyres with some XLC Street X Reflex tyres that have a puncture resist strip and I have had no more punctures in the last six months. This is with a mixture of road and green lane riding.
The XLC Street X Reflex tyres are cheap and low quality tyres - at the time I wanted to see if tyres were the cause of the punctures without spending a lot of money, and they clearly were. Next time I replace the tyres I will spend more and get a better tyre. But if you just want to see if the tyres are the cause then the XLC tyres would be a cheap experiment.

You may have a foreign object lodged in your tire that has poked through. Run your finger around the inside of the tire to see if you can feel anything sharp or otherwise not supposed to be there.
Of course, any new tire would work to fix this.

Run your finger around the inside of the tire...  If there is something sharp in the tire, that's a good way to mark it with a bit of blood.  Better to use something like a cotton ball that will catch on anything sharp.  Also, the tire might need to be flexed to actually expose something embedded into the tread.

@AndrewHenle that’s really not much a risk. In any case, cotton balls are useful as the snag on nearly anything and the material makes it easy to spot.

I'd say, first inspect visually, only if sure nothing is really protruding too much to be visible, use the finger carefully. If it only pokes very little, it may be hard to feel even with the finger. But make sure nothing is sticking out dangerously first. Cotton balls are not that much a thing everywhere, here when searching I only get very small ones (1 cm) in e-shops. But pads or tampons of other shapes should also work, I guess.

@PaulH maybe low chance of damage, but I’ve found some sharp things in my tire that would have cut my finger pretty badly if I’d just slid it along the tire.

@RLH, sure, but you can find those things easily without physically searching every bit of the tire’s interior surface. You only resort to what’s being described here when it’s otherwise impossible to locate, and therefore very small.

Some general advice:

Whenever you have a flat, always figure out what caused it. If you don’t figure out what the cause was and fix that problem, it’s a near certainty that the flat will happen again in the same way.
Whenever you replace a tube or otherwise unseat your tires, ensure they end up back on the rims in the exact same orientation. The usual recommendation is to line the manufacturer logo on the sidewalls up with the valve stem. This lets you quickly figure out where to look in the tire itself for foreign objects that could have caused a puncture in the tube.
When dealing with a flat caused by a puncture or tear on through the tire itself, keep in mind that small foreign objects may not be visible unless you flex the tire. This is especially true of small shards of glass, which may end up literally embedded within the tire itself such that they’re not visible at all from the outside and only protrude inside the tire when it’s flexed around the contact point with the road.
Carry a few cotton balls or gauze pads with you as part of your kit. They can be used to safely check for sharp objects protruding into the tire itself that you could not otherwise see. A small pair of fine-point pliers or a pair of forceps may also be helpful to remove such small objects.

In your specific case, it sounds like you have a very small sharp object embedded in the tire itself that’s slowly wearing a hole in the tube. These are a pain in the arse to find unless you approach the problem right (see the general advice above). If you’re lucky it will just fall out on it’s own as a result of you just flexing the tire, but realistically you need to find it and remove it.
If this assessment is accurate, a puncture-resistant or self-healing tube will just buy you time, and taking it to an LBS to get it looked at will just amount to you paying them to do the work of finding the foreign object and removing it (that may be worth it for you though). A new tire would obviously fix it, and a more puncture resistant one would of course reduce the probability of the issue happening again, but that will probably also impact how the bike rides. There’s also always the option of tire inserts (such as Tannus Armor Inserts) or tire liners (such as Slime Bicycle Tube Liners), both of which will work to prevent this type of issue, but they also will have a potentially significant impact on how the bike rides (likely far more noticeable than puncture-resistant tires).

For inner tubes, the only thing that works is to have an tire that is sturdy enough to avoid that debris reach the inner tube. It's also essential to learn how to patch a inner tube.
Self-healing inner tubes only work if the debris at the origin of the picture is removed, but in the majority of cases, you will need to unmount the tire to find the debris, so at this point you can just apply a patch. The sealant that is used in self-healing tubes has also a limited lifespan (if they use sealant that are similar to the ones used in tubeless tires, it's max 1 year) - tubes can last years, so after some time, you'll just end up with a normal tube.
Note that tires are often an area where manufacturer cheap out (especially on entry-level bikes). I'm normally against replacing parts of a bike before they wear out, tires are however an exception. If the fear of punctures discourage you from using your bike, better to throw away tires than leaving a bike unused. Quality tires not only offer better puncture protection, but also have a better compound, which improves rolling resistance and grip. Also if you use the bike for utility purposes, puncture resistance becomes a functional requirement of the bike.
(Another component that is worth replacing IMHO on entry-level bikes with rim brakes are the brake pads: as tires, the compound influences a lot how the brake behaves — better modulation, and often better in wet situations: it's a consumable anyway, so if there's only a marginal improvement, you can keep the current as spare)
